LS category of 4-manifolds with free fundamental group
In this math overflow question asked almost 5 years ago about the (normalized) Lusternik-Schnirelmann category of $4$-manifolds, the second-last comment (by Jeff Strom) says the following:

A $4$-dimensional compact manifold with free $\pi_1$ has L-S category $2$.

Specifically, if $\pi_1(M) = 0$ and $M \ne S^4$ is a $4$-manifold, then the above is true (as remarked by Mark Grant in the above question post). But I am not sure why the above statement is true for any $4$-manifold $M$ with $\pi_1(M)$ free and non-trivial. As observed by Oprea–Strom, it can be deduced from the work of Matumoto–Katanaga (and Hellen Colman) that the LS category of such manifolds is at most $2$. I don't understand why their LS category should be exactly $2$ (in particular, why can't it be $1$). Can someone please provide a reason/reference?

Well, compact manifolds (without boundary) are not contractible, for example since they have nontrivial mod 2 homology

@AchimKrause in the above context (and in the linked post), the LS category is normalized: it is $0$ if and only if space is contractible. So, for non-contractible spaces, LS category is at least $1$ (this does not explain why it should be $2$ in my above setting).

Ah, I see. Then let me try the following: $H^1(M;\mathbb{F}_2)$ is nontrivial since $\pi_1$ is free and nontrivial, and by Poincare duality there exists a class in $H^3(M;\mathbb{F}_2)$ such that their cup product is nontrivial, so the cup-length is $2$, which should imply LS category $\geq 2$

The time stamp of a comment is a link, which you can use to link to that particular comment. (There are some subtleties—see Links to comments when the title has been edited and a comment by @rene—but there's no need to worry about that unless you want to do so.) I have edited to refer to the comments you mentioned.

@AchimKrause can you please explain the existence of such a non-zero class in $H^3(M;\mathbb{F}_2)$ so that its cup product with the above-mentioned non-zero class in $H^1(M;\mathbb{F}_2)$ is non-trivial? Why is the cup product non-trivial?

One version of Poincare duality for unoriented Manifolds is that the cup-product pairing $H^i(M;\mathbb{F}_2)\otimes H^{n-i}(M;\mathbb{F}_2) \to H^n(M;\mathbb{F}_2)\cong \mathbb{F}_2$ is nondegenerate. I think this is for example discussed in Hatcher.

Suppose $X$ is a connected complex satisfying Poincaré duality over $\mathbb{Z}/2$. If $Cat(X)=1$, then $X$ is simply connected integral homology sphere. Thus the only closed 4-manifold with $Cat(X)=1$ is $S^4$ (no orientability assumptions are necessary). The proof is mostly spelled out above.

Yes, if $\pi_1(M)$ is free, then $H_1(M;\mathbb{Z})$ is free abelian (of the same rank), and then UCT determines $H^1(M;R)$.

Since we have settled on an argument in the comments, let me post it as an answer.
We have to show that a closed $4$-manifold with nontrivial free $\pi_1(M)$ does not have $\mathrm{cat}(M)=1$. Indeed, if $\pi_1(M)$ is free, $H_1(M)$ is free abelian, and so in particular $H^1(M;R)$ with any coefficients is nontrival by the universal coefficient theorem. One version of Poincaré duality [Hatcher, Algebraic Topology, Proposition 3.38] says that for closed $M$, the pairing
$$
H^i(M;\mathbb{F}_2) \otimes H^{n-i}(M;\mathbb{F}_2) \to H^n(M;\mathbb{F}_2)\cong \mathbb{F}_2
$$
is nondegenerate. In the case at hand, this means that for any nontrivial element of $H^1(M;\mathbb{F}_2)$, we find one in $H^3(M;\mathbb{F}_2)$ such that their cup product is nonzero. So $M$ has cup length at least $2$, and thus $\mathrm{cat}(M)\geq 2$.
In the comments, Tyrone mentioned a stronger result along those lines, namely that a closed connected manifold (or more generally Poincaré complex) with $\mathrm{cat}(M)=1$ must be a homology sphere. Indeed, in dimension $n=1$ there is nothing to show, and otherwise the above argument shows that $H^1(M;\mathbb{F}_2)=0$. But then $M$ is orientable, and so we have Poincaré duality with arbitrary coefficients and conclude that $H^i(M;K)=0$ for any $0<i<n$ and any field $K$. By a standard argument (using $K=\mathbb{F}_p$ and $\mathbb{Q}$) this shows that also the integral cohomology vanishes in those degrees, and thus that $M$ is a homology sphere.
(In the comments it was claimed that it suffices for $M$ to be a complex with Poincaré duality only with $\mathbb{F}_2$ coefficients, but I don't see how to argue then, and suspect something like the suspension of a Moore space with homology $\mathbb{Q}_2/\mathbb{Z}_2$ is a counterexample. This "looks like" a homology sphere with $\mathbb{F}_2$-coefficients, but not away from $2$.)
